# How got the reverse number?

Tags: java, reverse

I m not understanding the meaning of using this lines

this are on the while block.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseNumberWhile {
    public static void main(String[] args){

       int num = 0;
       int reversenum = 0;

       System.out.println("Enter your number and press enter: ");

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       num = input.nextInt();

       while(num != 0) {
           reversenum = reversenum * 10;
           reversenum = reversenum + num%10;
           num = num/10;
       }

       System.out.println("Reverse of input number is: " + reversenum);
   } 
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: @jannatin - can we have a selected answer to this please

Answer (score 2):

There you go,commented :

```
 while(num != 0)
       {
           reversenum = reversenum * 10; //This moves the reversenum attained in previous iteration to one higher place value
           reversenum = reversenum + num%10; // num%10 gives you the last digit which is added to the existing reversenum
           num = num/10; //This leaves the remaining digits removing rightmost
       }
```

Comment: what is the relation between num and reversenum here?

Comment: @jannatinnayemsourav `num` is the number you input. `reversenum` is the result you print out and is the first number in reverse order (if you ignore trailing zeros)

Answer (score 1):

This code produces the number `reversenum` with the same digits as `num`, but in reversed order. For example, if `num==12345`, then `reversenum==54321`. It works by chopping the digits of `num` one-by-one, starting with the last one, and adding them to `reversenum`. The loop can be described as follows:

1. Append the last digit of `num` to `reversenum` (the first two lines).
2. Remove the last digit of `num` (the last line).

This repeats as long as there are any digits left in `num`, that is, while it's non-zero.

The first two lines can actually be written as a single line:

```
reversenum = reversenum * 10 + num % 10;
```

This way it actually makes more sense because you can see what's going on here: we take `reversenum`, shift its digits to the left (by multiplying by 10) and then add the last digit of `num` (which is obtained by `num % 10`).